# Executing periodic tasks

Tags: go, timer

I am writing a code in Golang to execute a periodic function (every 2 second). According to documentation and an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466320/is-there-a-way-to-do-repetitive-tasks-at-intervals-in-golang) I have written two programs. Can anybody tell which one is better? Also, is there another better solution?

**Code 1:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func periodicFunc(tick time.Time){
    fmt.Println("Tick at: ", tick)
}

func main(){
    fmt.Println("Starting a new ticker....")

    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    go func(){
        for t := range ticker.C {
            //Call the periodic function here.
            periodicFunc(t)
        }
    }()

    quit := make(chan bool, 1)
    // main will continue to wait untill there is an entry in quit
    <-quit
}
```

**Code 2:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func periodicFunc(tick time.Time){
    fmt.Println("Tick at: ", tick)
}
func main(){
    ticker := time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)

    go func() {
        for {
           select {
            case <- ticker.C:
                //Call the periodic function here.
                periodicFunc(<- ticker.C)
            }
        }
     }()

    quit := make(chan bool, 1)
    // main will continue to wait untill there is an entry in quit
    <-quit
}
```

Answer (score 10):

[A vs. B type questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) are seldom good questions for a code review. Often the answer is "C".

That's true this time too.

- You don't need a go routine for the "ticker".
- Your second implementation only waits for 1 second, instead of 2.
- your "quit" channels don't need to be buffered

Why don't you just do:

```
func main() {
    for t := range time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second).C {
        periodicFunction(t)
    }
}
```

Comment: So, how do you quit from this loop? You need a select inside the loop again, right?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/16466561/4196282; it shows how to use the channel that a Ticker contains.